# How to make my web page look Ok with IE7+?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I recently refactored my web site to use HTML5. It works Ok with most browsers except, obviously, with IE7 and IE8.

It looks like it result from the use of the <header>, <section> and <article> tags which are apparently ignored by IE7. My css defines specific tag formating subclasses for these.

```
header { color: #fff;  background: url("background1.jpg"); 
        padding: 10px 40px 20px 40px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
header a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; outline: none; }
header a:hover { color: #fff; text-decoration: underline; }
header h1 { color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; 
          padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 0px; }
header h2 { color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
header hr { margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px; }
header .copyright { font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; 
    padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 0px; }

section { padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px; line-height: normal; }

article .main { font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: normal; }
```

I skipped other style definition that don't cause a problem.

How could I get around this problem ? Do I have to drop the HTML5 tags ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this script in your head section:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Does most of the html5 work in IE for me :-)

Comment: I must admit it is pretty impressive for HTML and browsers to support such backward compatibility possibility.

Comment: I know it's amazing isn't it. It would be even better if we stopped having so much trouble using IE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that browsers have special treatment for tags they don't recognize at all; basic things like styles being applied and being able to contain sub-items won't work.

Html shivs, such as that linked by RTB, will inject the basic recognition of those html5 tags in via javascript so the browser recognizes them as valid tags, meaning you can then style them.

Libraries such as Modernizr also include an html5 shiv (though otherwise, Modernizr does not enable html5 functionality)
Note that a shiv does not generally allow anything but basic tag recognition, so you can style the elements. it does not enable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and create elements in javascript and IE will render it.

```
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('article');
```